# How to get shipping address from quote object in custom js file magento 2

Tags: checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I want to apply a functionality that enables , dynamic billing address to be changed as per changing shipping address in checkout page magento 2.
How to get shipping address from quote object in custom js file magento 2 ?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the shipping address from the quote js model in your custom js file.

Use below code to access shipping address in your custom js file:

```
define(
        [
            'ko',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
        ],
        function (
                ko,
                quote
                ) {
            'use strict';

            return {
                yourFunctionName: function () {

                    var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                    var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
                }
            };
        }
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it returns null.